# Can you detect INSERT-EXEC scenario's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, raiserror

Is it possible to DETECT whether the current stored procedure is being called by an `INSERT-EXEC` statement?

Yes, I understand we may want to no longer use `INSERT-EXEC` statements...that is NOT the question I am asking.

The REASON I am using `INSERT-EXEC` is because i am hoping to promote re-use of stored procedures rather than re-writing the same SQL all the time.

**Here's why I care:**

Under the `INSERT-EXEC` scenario the original error message will get lost once a `ROLLBACK` is requested.  As such, any records created will now be orphaned.

**Example:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spa_DoSomething]
(
    @SomeKey    INT,
    @CreatedBy  NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- SQL runs and throws an error of some kind.

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN

        -- If this procedure is called using an INSERT-EXEC
        -- then the original error will be lost at this point because
        -- "Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement." 
        -- will come-up instead of the original error.

        SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        SET @ErrorSeverity =    ERROR_SEVERITY();
        SET @ErrorState =       ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    END CATCH

    RETURN @@Error
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe @@NESTLEVEL can help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187371.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a bit of a kludge (ok, it's a big kludge), based on the fact that you can't have nested `INSERT--EXECUTE`... statements. Basically, if your "problem" procedure is the target of an `INSERT--EXECUTE`, and itself contains an `INSERT--EXECUTE`, then an error will be raised. To make this work, you'd have to have a (quite probably pointless) `INSERT--EXECUTE` call in the procedure, and wrap it in a `TRY--CATCH` block with appropriate handling. Awkward and obtuse, but if nothing else comes up it might be worth a try.

Use the following to test it out. This will create three procedures:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.Foo1'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Foo1
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.Foo2'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Foo2
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.Foo3'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Foo3

GO
--  Returns a simple data set
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo1

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    SELECT name
     from sys.databases

GO
--  Calls Foo1, loads data into a local temp table, then returns those contents
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo2

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    CREATE TABLE #Temp (DBName sysname not null)

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT #Temp (DBName)
         EXECUTE Foo1
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 8164
            PRINT 'Nested INSERT EXECUTE'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Unanticipated err: ' + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(10))
    END CATCH


    SELECT *
     from #Temp

GO
--  Calls Foo2, loads data into a local temp table, then returns those contents
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo3

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (DBName sysname not null)

    INSERT #Temp2 (DBName)
     EXECUTE Foo2

    SELECT *
     from #Temp2
GO
```

`EXECUTE Foo1` will return the "base" data set.

`EXECUTE Foo2` will call Foo1, load the data into a temp table, and then return the contents of that table.

`EXECUTE Foo3` attempts to do the same thing as Foo2, but it calls Foo2. This results in a nested `INSERT--EXECUTE` error, which is detected and handled by Foo2's `TRY--CATCH`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a practical solution in most cases, but +1 for the sheer ingenuity :)

Comment: Thanks for the input...I'll have to look at this in a moment.  In the meantime, we don't really have a MULTI-NEST scenario going-on (only 1 level).  Is there a better way to do this that still promotes re-use of stored procedures?

Comment: I came up with this kludge because I don't know of, can't think of, and can't even imagine SQL providing a means to detect that a given EXECUTE was called as part of an INSERT statement. This does assume that you don't currently have nested insert executes,  because if you did, you'd be complaining about that (I sure have!)

Comment: If it turns out this cannot be detected, I'd advise you explicitly denote when a proc is or is not being called via INSERT. This is as simple (and as awkward) as adding and properly assigning a new parameter, such as `@CalledByInsert  bit`. Awkward, because you'd have to check and perhaps modify a lot of code.

Comment: I guess my REAL struggle is "how do you properly promote code re-use of stored procs"?  If I have to eliminate the INSERT-EXECS and paste the proc's code in every parental call...that "seems" even worse.  Do you have any ideas there?

Comment: If the procedure does not modify (insert, update, delete) data, but just returns (select, no matter how complex), changing it to a function might help.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm not clear on what your actual problem is -- soemthing with data being lost or corrupted due to transaction rollbacks? This doesn't sound like an insert--execute problem so much as a transaction processing problem. If so, you might want to spell it out in more detail as a new SO question.